# Why does my indexed column appear not to have statistics?

Tags: sql-server-2008, statistics

I'm using SQL Server and I'm currently trying to debug some queries where the optimizer has chosen a poor execution plan and I noticed for one of my indexed columns that when I run the command:

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ("tablename", columnname);
```

for this indexed column, the database returns:

**Could not locate statistics 'columnname' in the system catalogs.**

According to this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190397.aspx

"The query optimizer creates statistics for indexes on tables or views when the index is created."

I also have AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS on.

Should I have to manually have to run a CREATE STATISTICS for this column?  If so, since it's an index shouldn't it already have statistics for the column?

Comment: Any sign of it in `SELECT * FROM sys.stats WHERE object_id=object_id('tablename')`? Is this index a composite index or just a single column index? Also the index itself isn't showing up as disabled in `sys.indexes`?

Comment: It shows up in the sys.stats table with the name of the index: 'IX_cl_messages_sent_time' and it shows a stats id of 3, all the other columns in that table are 0.  It is a single column index on a datetime type column.  The index isn't disabled in the sys.indexes table.

Comment: What if you try `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ("tablename", IX_cl_messages_sent_time);`?

Comment: That worked! Thanks!  I'm not sure why other indexes were showing up by just using the column name and not the index name.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-show-statistics-transact-sql:

> If target is the name of an existing column, and an automatically
>   created statistics on this column exists, information about that
>   auto-created statistic is returned. If an automatically created
>   statistic does not exist for a column target, error message 2767 is
>   returned.

So specifying the name of the index for target (the second parameter) will work, but it won't work if you use the column name.

If you run this (credit to Erland Sommarskog, http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html), you can see if stats were auto-created or not:

```
DECLARE @tbl NVARCHAR(256)
SELECT @tbl = 'tableName'

SELECT
  o.name, s.stats_id, s.name, s.auto_created, s.user_created,
  SUBSTRING(scols.cols, 3, LEN(scols.cols)) AS stat_cols,
  STATS_DATE(o.object_id, s.stats_id) AS stats_date,
  s.filter_definition
FROM
  sys.objects o JOIN
  sys.stats s ON s.object_id = o.object_id
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT ', ' + c.name
  FROM
    sys.stats_columns sc JOIN
    sys.columns c ON sc.object_id = c.object_id AND sc.column_id = c.column_id
  WHERE sc.object_id = s.object_id AND sc.stats_id = s.stats_id
  ORDER BY sc.stats_column_id
  FOR XML PATH('')
) AS scols(cols)
WHERE o.name = @tbl
ORDER BY o.name, s.stats_id
```